# Ajax Call Success, Post not actually sent

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, json

I have tried removing the `JSON.stringify` and changing the post to get change cache to false and true. I am at a loss as to what needs to happen. It always goes to the else statement in my php and returns the default JSON. I have allowed crossdomain in my php with the wildcard so that is definitely not the problem.

#### Code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.check').click(function(){

var thisID    = $(this).attr('id');
alert(thisID);
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    crossDomain: true,
    url: "retrieveColumn.php",
    data: JSON.stringify({ ID: thisID}),
    cache: true,
    async:true,
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data)
    {
        console.log(data);
        alert(data);
    }
    
});
}); 
});
```

PHP which always goes to the else condition:

```
if(isset($_POST['ID']))
{
$ID = $_POST['ID'];

{

$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  group2.menu  WHERE ItemID = $ID ");

 if($stmt->num_rows) //if there is an ID of this name
 {  
$row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
echo $row;
 print json_encode($row);   

}
}
 }
else
{
 $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  group2.menu  WHERE ItemID = 2");
  $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
 print json_encode($row);   
}
```

Comment: what is the output of print_r($_POST) in your alert(data) ?

Comment: Is `group2.menu` the name of your table? I think it should be `menu`.

Answer (score 1):

Unless this is part of a larger document, you have unnecessary brackets which might be causing problems.

```
if(isset($_POST['ID'])){
$ID = $_POST['ID'];

{ /* <!-- HERE! What is this?? */

$stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  group2.menu  WHERE ItemID = $ID ");

 if($stmt->num_rows) //if there is an ID of this name{  
 $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
 echo $row;
 print json_encode($row);   

}
}
 }
else
{
 $stmt = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM  group2.menu  WHERE ItemID = 2");
  $row = $stmt->fetch_assoc();
 print json_encode($row);   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify the object you submit as data here:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ ID: thisID}),
```

Use:

```
data: { ID: thisID},
```